# Keeping Kendo pagination state after clicking on details URL and returning to page two

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

The problem in the below line of code is when I click on the details URL on page two and comeback to that page the kendo shows me page 1. How can I selected the current page and if a person has make some sorting on that column?

```
"<tr class='#:IsCancel==true? \"red\" : \"white\"#' data-uid='#: uid #'>" + "<td class='id' style = 'text-align:right;width:165px'>" +
                     //"<a class = 'k-button del' title='ختم کریں' href='" + Url.Action("Delete", "Affiliation") + "/#= id #'" + "><span class='k-icon k-delete'></span></a>" + 
                     "<a title='سندالحاق' class = 'sanad btn btn-primary btn-sm'>سندالحاق</a><a class = 'k-button pre1' title='پرنٹ کریں'><span class='fa fa-print'></span></a>" +
                     "<a class = 'k-button View' title='تفصیل' href='" + Url.Action("Details", "Affiliation") + "/#= id #'" + "><span class='fa fa-list-alt'></span></a>" +
                     "<a class = 'k-button edit' title='تبدیل کریں' href='" + Url.Action("Edit", "Affiliation") + "/#= id #'" + "><span class='fa fa-pencil'></span></a>" + "</td>" +
                 "<td class='NazamName'>#:(NazamName == null) ? ' ' : NazamName #" + "</td>" +
                 "<td class='Phone'>#:(Phone == null) ? ' ' : Phone #" + "</td>" +
                 "<td class='District'>#:(District == null) ? ' ' : District #" + "</td>" +
                 "<td class='Province'>#:(Province == null) ? ' ' : Province #" + "</td>" +
                 "<td class='AffiliationsStatus'>#: AffiliationsStatus #" + "</td>" + "<td class='Address'>#: Address #" + "</td>" +
                 "<td class='JamiaName'>#: JamiaName #" + "</td>" + "<td class='AffiliationID'>#: AffiliationID #" + "</td>" +
                 "<td class='IsCancel' style='display:none'>" + "#: IsCancel #" + "</td>" +
                "</tr>"
```